# ElasticSearch: Impact of setting a "not_analyzed" field as "store":"yes"?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a string field specified as `not_analyzed` in the mapping. If I then add `"store":"yes"` to the mapping, will ElasticSearch duplicate the storage? My understanding of `not_analyzed` fields is that they are not run through an Analyzer, indexed *as is*, but a client is able to match against it. So, if a field is both `not_analyzed` and `store:yes`, this could cause ElasticSearch to keep two copies of the string.

My question:

- If a string field is stored as both `not_analyzed` and `store:yes`, will there be duplicate storage of the string?

I hope that's clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You're mixing up the concept of indexed field and stored field in lucene, the library that elasticsearch is built on top of.

A field is indexed when it goes within the inverted index, the data structure that lucene uses  to provide its great and fast full text search capabilities. If you want to search on a field, you do have to index it. When you index a field you can decide whether you want to index it as it is, or you want to analyze it, which means deciding a tokenizer to apply to it, which will generate a list of tokens (words) and a list of token filters that can modify the generated tokens (even add or delete some). The way you index a field affects how you can search on it. If you index a field but don't analyze it, and its text is composed of multiple words, you'll be able to find that document only searching for that exact specific text, whitespaces included.

A field is stored when you want to be able to retrieve it. Let's say Lucene provides some kind of storage too, which doesn't have anything to do with the inverted index itself.
When you search using lucene you get back a list of document ids that match. Then you can retrieve some text from their stored fields, which is what you literally show as search results. If you don't store a field you'll never be able to get it back from lucene (this is not true for elasticsearch though, as I'm going to explain below).

You can have fields that you only want to search on, and never show: indexed and not stored (default in lucene).
You can have fields that you want to search on and also retrieve: indexed and stored.
You can have fields that you don't want to search on, but you do want to retrieve to show them.

Therefore the two data structures are not related to each other. If you both index and store a field in lucene, its content will not be present twice in the same form. Stored fields are stored as they are, as you send them to lucene, while indexed fields might be analyzed and will be part of the inverted index, which is something else. Stored fields are made to be retrieved for a specific document (by lucene document id), while indexed fields are made to search, in such a structure that literally inverts the text having as a result each term as key, together with a list of document ids that contain it (the postings list).

When it comes to elasticsearch things change a little though. When you don't configure a field as stored in your mapping (default is `store:no`) you are able to retrieve it anyway by default. This happens because elasticsearch always stores in lucene the whole source document that you send to it (unless you disable this feature) within a special lucene field, called [_source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field.html).

When you search using elasticsearch you get back by default the whole source field, but you can also ask for specific fields. What happens in that case is that elasticsearch checks whether those specific fields are stored or not in lucene. If they are the content will be retrieved from lucene, otherwise the `_source` stored field will be retrieved from lucene, parsed as json (pull parsing) and those specific fields will be extracted. In the first case it might be a little faster, but not necessarily. If your source is really big and you only want to load a couple of fields, configuring them as stored in lucene would probably make the loading process faster; on the other hand, if your `_source` is not that big and you want to load many fields, then it's probably better to load only one stored field (the `_source`), which would lead to a single disk seek, parse it etc. In most of the cases using the `_source` field works just fine.

To answer your question: inverted index and lucene storage are two completely different things. You end up having two copies of the same data in lucene only if you decide to store a field (`store:yes` in the mapping), since elasticsearch keeps that same content within the json `_source`, but this doesn't have anything to do with the fact that you're indexing or analyzing the field.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the difference to some degree (though you clarified a few things, thankfully!), my question was more towards: if we're going to be storing large quantities of short (~ 80-character strings) that we need to both retrieve and perform exact-matches against (by analyzing them with "not_analyzed"), is there essentially duplication of data between the index and wherever fields are stored. It looks like there is, but as you explained, their nature and usage is very different, so it's not real duplication.

Comment: We have `_source` as `false` for most of our fields.

Comment: Ok, if you have `_source` false you have nothing to worry about. It's like doing two different things with the same data. The two data structures (inverted index and storage) are completely different and have different purposes. There's not even a way to avoid this, unless you want to get back from lucene/elasticsearch only document ids of matching documents and use some other external storage.

Comment: Just a small comment on an excellent answer; Using the _source field would be quicker than - say - storing 10 different fields and asking for them since this would imply more fetching from disk than just fetching the _source. As a golden rule; prefer _source to store unless very good reasons not to, e.g a monstrously big _source.

Comment: @javanna This is something i once read from the pen of Shay. Ok, I managed to find it again: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/What-does-it-mean-to-quot-store-quot-a-field-td3514176.html