# Elasticsearch: do I need store="yes" when index="not_analyzed"?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have a field `f1` with value `str` (String).

if `index="not_analyzed"` is set for field `f1`, then value `str` is stored (as an entry) into the inverted index, because it's not splitted into tokens.

if I set `store="yes"` too, then (IMHO), the value `str` is going to be recorded another one, so twice in the end.

So, **first question**, if `index="not_analyzed"`, what's the added value of `store="yes"`? 
To say things differently, as this second storage (due to `store="yes"`) has a cost, what new capabilities are brought by `store="yes"` **that are not possible otherwise, even if** the `str` is already stored into the inverted index?

IMHO, the same case could appear if the field is not a String, but a date (or a long or an integer).
Let's say we have a field `f2` like `"type": "date"` and `"precision_step" : "0"`.

if I set `store="yes"` too, then (IMHO), the value of `f2` is going to be recorded twice in the end.

So, **second question**, if `"precision_step"="0"`, what's the added value of `store="yes"`?
To say things differently, as this second storage induced by `store="yes"` has a cost, what new capabilities are brought by `store="yes"`?

PS: it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299799/elasticsearch-impact-of-setting-a-not-analyzed-field-as-storeyes)
In fact, this new question is all about questioning what has been **NOT** answered into this previous one.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are, just like the SO post referenced, mixing things up. Indexing and storing are two different things. You index tokens (either analyzed or not) to be able to search afterwards in a very very quick manner.

It has nothing to do with storing the actual field value in the inverted index. These are separate operations and separate things. If you don't store a field and you disable "_source" field then you are using ES just for searching, even if you have the inverted index with the field value in there. If you actually need to retrieve the original document (or the original value in a field that **matched**) then you can't. You either need _source or `"store": yes`.

Basically, if `_source` is disabled and `"store"` is `no` then you are only able to get back only the _id of the document. If you need the content then you go to your secondary storage option (DB database, for example) and, based on the _id, you get the actual content. It doesn't matter if your field is "analyzed" or "not_analyzed", as long as you have no other way of **storing the original document or the original field value**, then ES is used for searching only (as opposed to **store** and search).

Everything below is to be considered when "_source" is disabled. Regarding the `store=yes` capabilities, one is above - being able to retrieve the content, not only searching. The second is highlighting. Without storing, one cannot highlight tokens in a field.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.
Do I mix search and store ? yes and no.
I just thought different features/algorithms may share common data, may rely on some common parts (see OOP: a class may provide different methods on top of the same class fields)

So, I thought that, in **some** circumstances, while the inverted index and the storage unit (for store="yes") include the same data (see my examples above), Elasticsearch may have able to retrieve data even if store="no".

From your sentences, I guess that, even if this might be possible (?), this is not currently provided in Elasticsearch.

Comment: From what I read, these two "features" are separate and there is no link between the inverted index when there is a not_analyzed field and a `store=yes` option so that memory usage, for example, to be improved.