# Elasticsearch java query optimization

Tags: java, performance, optimization, elasticsearch

I have a document with the following fields A, B, C, D, E.

I can query to get the values of A and B in the following 2 ways

Method 1:

```
    SearchResponse response1 = client
            .prepareSearch("indexname")
            .setTypes("all")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), FilterBuilders.termFilter("C", "SOME_VALUE")))
            .execute().actionGet();
```

Then parse the source to get Field A and B.

Method 2

```
    String[] fields = {"A", "B"};
    SearchResponse response1 = client
            .prepareSearch("indexname")
            .setTypes("all")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), FilterBuilders.termFilter("C", "SOME_VALUE")))
            .addFields(fields)
            .execute().actionGet();
```

Now parse the fields itself directly instead of source.

I compared the time took by both queries. The results were inconsistent. However, the response times were skewed to be lower towards Method 2. But it was not definite. So can anyone tell me for sure, which method is faster and why?

Answer (score 0):

For each result document, first method has to fetch the values of all fields while the second method only has to fetch the values of fields A and B. That's the reason method 2 is faster. Method 2 is also cleaner as in you get the values of fields A and B directly and you don't need to apply custom parsing logic on the client side.

Any reason why you've enabled the `_source` field? Fetching the value of `_source` field will of course take additional time, not to mention it incurs storage overhead in the index too. See [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) for more information. So unless absolutely necessary you can try disabling the `_source` field.

Comment: I am a newbie to ES. So you mean to say, in my mappings for the index, I should make 'store: yes' and disable _source?

Comment: according to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299799/elasticsearch-impact-of-setting-a-not-analyzed-field-as-storeyes

If I disable _source, it will be one disk read for each field I want to fetch. And _source enabled gives me all fields in one disk read. And what I essentially need is to be able to get any field based on a particular value of some field. Much like a database.

Comment: The logic of one disk read for `_source` field applies only when the document is very small with lots of fields to be read. In your case it does not look like it. Marking `store` as `yes` and disabling `_source` should be good enough for you.