# Nest update index settings

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am following the post [Creating an index Nest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220874/creating-an-index-nest) and trying to update my index settings. All runs fine however the `html_strip` filter is not stripping HTML. My code is

```cs
var node = new Uri(_url + ":" + _port);
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
settings.SetDefaultIndex(index);
_client = new ElasticClient(settings);

//to apply filters during indexing use folding to remove diacritics and html strip to remove html
_client.UpdateSettings(
        f = > f.Analysis(descriptor = > descriptor
                .Analyzers(
                        bases = > bases
                        .Add("folded_word", new CustomAnalyzer
                        {
                        Filter = new List < string > { "icu_folding", "trim" },
                                Tokenizer = "standard"
                        }
                        )
                        )
                .CharFilters(
                        cf = > cf.Add("html_strip", new HtmlStripCharFilter())
                        )
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error:

> Can't update non dynamic
>   settings[[index.analysis.analyzer.folded_word.filter.0,
>   index.analysis.char_filter.html_strip.type,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.folded_word.filter.1,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.folded_word.type,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.folded_word.tokenizer]] for open
>   indices[[my_index]]

Before you will try to update settings, close index first, update settings and reopen afterwards. [Have a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758335/error-when-trying-to-update-the-settings)

```cs
client.CloseIndex(..);

client.UpdateSettings(..);

client.OpenIndex(..);
```

***UPDATE***

Add `html_strip` char filter to you custom analyzer:

```cs
.Analysis(descriptor => descriptor
                    .Analyzers(bases => bases.Add("folded_word",
                        new CustomAnalyzer
                        {
                            Filter = new List<string> { "icu_folding", "trim" }, 
                            Tokenizer = "standard", 
                            CharFilter = new List<string> { "html_strip" }
                        }))
                )
```

Now you can run test to check if this analyzer returns correct tokens:

```cs
client.Analyze(a => a.Index(indexName).Text("this <a> is a test <div>").Analyzer("folded_word"));
```

Output:

```
this
is
a
test
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Rob, many thanks your suggestion worked I can see the filter however during indexing html is not being stripped.

Comment: @Ismail may you share index mapping?

Comment: `{
umbracotest: {
settings: {
index: {
uuid: "eb3hMpFrS8qyb3DxHZ4_eg",
analysis: {
char_filter: {
html_strip: {
type: "html_strip"
}
}
},
number_of_replicas: "1",
number_of_shards: "5",
version: {
created: "1020099"
}
}
}
}
}`

Comment: Rob, your update and testing with Analyze works many thanks.  However when I index the html is still there.  When doing Index do you have to pass in which analyser to use?  I am assuming it infers from what is set during client init?

Comment: @Ismail I think I understand your concerns right now. Your content with html tags has been indexed using folded_word analyzer, but what you are getting is the original content not indexed tokens. Hope it's clear enough. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html) you can find more info how elasticsearch works under the hood.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299799/elasticsearch-impact-of-setting-a-not-analyzed-field-as-storeyes/15320692#15320692) one should be quite useful too.

Comment: Rob,ah makes sense I was querying with sense and still seeing the html. Once again many thanks for your help